# Having ConcurrentModificationException exception after trying separate entity manager for read and write

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, quarkus

I have prepared separate JDBC configurations for read and write purposes on quarks application. When trying to execute the service method to get results and write the method from the service class method, getting the following exception
**Statck trace**

```
 > java.util.ConcurrentModificationException\n\tat
    > java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1221)\n\tat
    > io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.RequestScopedSessionHolder.getOrCreateSession(RequestScopedSessionHolder.java:21)\n\tat
    > io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.RequestScopedSessionHolder_ClientProxy.getOrCreateSession(Unknown
    > Source)\n\tat
    > io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.TransactionScopedSession.acquireSession(TransactionScopedSession.java:103)\n\tat
    > io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.TransactionScopedSession.createQuery(TransactionScopedSession.java:356)\n\tat
    > org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionLazyDelegator.createQuery(SessionLazyDelegator.java:547)\n\tat
    > org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionLazyDelegator.createQuery(SessionLazyDelegator.java:65)\n\tat
    > org.hibernate.Session_fa5422f4bd76316308253b9ba0cef11c854fad1c_Synthetic_ClientProxy.createQuery(Unknown
    > Source)\n\tat
    > com.coda.codapay.payout.param.repository.PaymentMethodTypeHibernateEntityRepository.lambda$findByType$1(PaymentMethodTypeHibernateEntityRepository.java:46)\n\tat
    > io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualFunction.apply(SlowContextualFunction.java:21)\n\tat
    > io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform$UniOnItemTransformProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransform.java:36)\n\tat
    > io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniEmitOn$UniEmitOnProcessor.lambda$onItem$0(UniEmitOn.java:34)\n\tat
    > io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)\n\tat
    > org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)\n\tat
    > org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)\n\tat
    > org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)\n\tat
    > org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)\n\tat
    > io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)\n\tat
    > java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)"
```

**Repository class :**

```
@ApplicationScoped public class PaymentMethodTypeHibernateEntityRepository implements PaymentMethodTypeRepository { private final Vertx vertx;
    private final EntityManager readEntityManager;

    public PaymentMethodTypeHibernateEntityRepository(Vertx vertx,
                                                      @PersistenceUnit("read")  EntityManager readEntityManager) {
        this.vertx = vertx;
        this.readEntityManager = readEntityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Uni<PaymentMethodType> findByType(String type) {
        return Uni.createFrom()
                .voidItem()
                .emitOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultExecutor())
                .onItem()
                .transform(unused -> (HibernatePaymentMethodType) readEntityManager.createQuery("SELECT paymentMethodType FROM HibernatePaymentMethodType paymentMethodType WHERE paymentMethodType.name = :type")
                        .setParameter("type", type)
                        .getSingleResult())
                .emitOn(MutinyHelper.executor(vertx))
                .onItem()
                .ifNotNull()
                .transform(HibernatePaymentMethodType::toPaymentMethodType);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please format stacktrace a little better? It's very hard to read currently

Comment: @geoand, format done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching and analyzing the issue. Found the way to solve the issue. We can apply Transaction call so that Hibernate does not try to execute parallel execution. If mysql support reactive mode we can configure reactive mode of configuration

```
@Override
public Uni<PaymentMethodType> findByType(String type) {
    return Uni.createFrom()
            .voidItem()
            .emitOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultExecutor())
            .onItem()
            .transform(unused -> getByType(type))
            .emitOn(MutinyHelper.executor(vertx))
            .onItem()
            .ifNotNull()
            .transform(HibernatePaymentMethodType::toPaymentMethodType);
}
@Transactional
private HibernatePaymentMethodType getByType(String type) {
    return QuarkusTransaction.call(() -> (HibernatePaymentMethodType) readEntityManager.createQuery
                    ("SELECT paymentMethodType FROM HibernatePaymentMethodType paymentMethodType WHERE paymentMethodType.type = :type")
            .setParameter("type", type).getSingleResult());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are trying to use reactive code with Hibernate ORM (that's not reactive). Because the code is reactive, some operations are happening in parallel, causing the exception.

If you want to write reactive code, you should check [Hibernate Reactive](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-reactive).